# Will I mess up any kind of process if I accidenally hit a key on the keyboard?

Tags: software-installation

You know like on the command screen

[image: will it mess up if I accidentally hit a key? Could it write a code or script wrong or something?]

will it mess up if I accidentally hit a key? Could it write a code or script wrong or install something wrong?

Comment: Not likely with a single key, but you could interrupt a process with key combos like ctrl-c. However, that does not mean you should be randomly typing or letting your cat walk on the keyboard when a process is running.

Comment: I know ctrl-alt-delete will reboot, should I do this if it gets stuck? Or will it mess up a program or something?

Comment: If it gets stuck I would try ctrl-c, ctrl-z, ctrl-d or ctrl-x first. I would leave ctrl-alt-del as a last resort. All of these can leave the Pi in an unstable state (half installed/configured state). I would also make sure it is truly stuck as depending on what the Pi is doing it may take quite a while (compiling some packages can take many hours if done on the Pi). I would also check that any lockup/freeze is not the result of a power issue.

Comment: Could you explain to me what c z d and x do?

Comment: They are the vearious interrupt quit commands used by various programs on Linux

Comment: @kyranbullard C does [SIGINT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT), Z does [SIGSTOP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGSTOP), d does [EOF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character), and x is done by the application. See the Wikipedia links for what those mean.

Answer (score -1):

No it won't. Except  for (Ctrl + c) as it will terminate the process.

Comment: That's two keys!

Comment: Good point. 'q' can cause problem .not sure